# How can I open a separate process in file explorer and search using vba

Tags: vba, shell, ms-access, windows-explorer

I'm Using MS Access and VBA.I'm trying to open a separate process in windows file explorer and then search for a file.

Using:

```
vPID = Shell("""explorer.exe""" & Chr(34) & """search ms:query=*.pdf&crumb=location:c:\""" & Chr(34),vbNormalFocus)
```

I can open explorer and search.

Using:

```
vPID = Shell("explorer.exe /separate", vbNormalFocus)
```

I can open explore as a separate process

If I add the switch `/separate` to the code then the search doesn't run.
Does anyone know how I can combine the two to work together i.e. open file explorer as a separate process and run a search? I've tried every combination I can think of